# Pull-down resistor is needed?

Tags: arduino, hardware

I am using the `attachInterrupt()` function in *Arduino One* to recognize the limit of an actuator. Typically I test it as `if()`, but the actuator cycle is very fast and recognition thereby becomes complicated. Thus I chose to use `attachInterrupt()`, but I do not know if in the case of interruption I must use pull-down resistor at the input. Someone could tell me if this is needed?

Currently the system is shown below:

[image]

Piece of code:

```
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin2), EndCourse2, FALLING);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin3), EndCourse3, FALLING);

void EndCourse2() {
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);
  btnpressed2=0;
}

void EndCourse3() {
  if(btnpressed2==0) {
    digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
    CounterAT2++;
  }
  btnpressed2=1;
}
```

Comment: Despite my answer, I think the question is better suited at [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: A pull-up design is always preferable to a pull-down.  In this specific case, it would save you a resistor, since the MCU provides internal pull-ups.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about electronics not programming. Please post such questions on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a pull-down resistor in this case.

The digital input of the Arduino has a high impedance, which can be though of an insulating input. If you omit the resistor and consider the case when the switch is open, the input of the Arduino is *floating*. This means the digital input is not connected to any potential. Electromagnetical interference will induce currents into your circuit. Basically, the voltage at the input can change from low to high due to this interference.

To define the state of the input, when the switch is open, you should add the resistor, which ensures, that the input is at low, independent of electromagentical interference.

If you mirror your circuit, such that the switch is connect to ground and the resistor is connect to `Vcc`, you can move the pull up resistor into the Arduoin by setting the input mode to `INPUT_PULLUP`. Since then an internal resistor is used, you can drop the resistor outside.

Comment: Thanks, I kept my resistor pulling down and I changed the attachInterrupt () parameter, before I used FALLING, but it was not correct for that, so I switched to LOW, since my input is always receiving HIGH and I want to recognize when LOW.

Comment: You should also looking into [bouncing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce).

Comment: ... and not using interrupts makes everything ( including debouncing) much easier.